# 'syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure' on a line that doesn't exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I'm getting the error: [syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting $end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUU42.png) on a haml template I have, but the extracted source line number it's pulling out is past the end of the file. My code is:

```
%span
* click a gamertag to see detailed medal stats

.seperator{ :id => 'medal-stats', :style => 'margin: 20px 0 20px 0;' }

- @sorted_players.each do |player|
  .medal_stats{ :id => "player_medals_#{Digest::MD5.hexdigest(player['Gamertag'])}" }
    %h3
      #{player['Gamertag']}'s Medals

  %table.team-table.table.table-bordered.table-striped.table-hover
    %thead
      %tr
        - @metadata['MedalsMetadata']['MedalClasses'].each do |medal_class|
          %td
            #{medal_class['Name']}

    %tbody
      - player['MedalStats'] = player['MedalStats'].sort_by { |medal| medal['TotalMedals'] }.reverse
        %tr
          - @metadata['MedalsMetadata']['MedalClasses'].each do |medal_class|
            %td
              - player['MedalStats'].each do |medal|
                - if medal['ClassId'] != medal_class['Id']
                  - next

                .medal-entry{ :style => "background-image: ('#{ X343ApiController.asset_url_generator_basic( medal['ImageUrl']['BaseUrl'],
                medal['ImageUrl']['AssetUrl'], 'medium') }');" }
                  #{medal['TotalMedals']}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by the lines:

```
- player['MedalStats'] = player['MedalStats'].sort_by { |medal| medal['TotalMedals'] }.reverse
  %tr
```

The `%tr` shouldn’t be indented, you should move it back (and the lines indented under it) to be in line with the `-player ...` line above.

To see why this error is created we need to look at how Haml parses scripts. When a script line has a section indented under it, Haml assumes that it is a block that should be passed as part of the script, and produces the appropriate code including a generated `end` statement. For example this Haml:

```
- @things.each do |thing|
  %li= thing
```

generates Ruby that looks something like

```
 @things.each do |thing|
_hamlout.buffer << "<li>#{thing
}</li>\n";end;
```

The first line (`@things.each do |thing|`) is copied direct from the Haml source, but the corresponding `end` is generated by Haml. Also note how the `end` is put on a trailing line, so that it doesn’t match up with the lines in the Haml and the error appears to come from beyond the end of your source.

If the script line doesn’t start a block, Haml doesn’t notice and still assumes a block has been opened and generates the `end` statement anyway. For example the Haml

```
- a_variable = just_set_the_var
  %li= thing
```

Generates the following Ruby:

```
 a_variable = just_set_the_var
_hamlout.buffer << "<li>#{a_variable
}</li>\n";end;
```

The first line is copied directly from the Haml, and since it doesn’t contain a `do |...|`, the `end` that Haml generates is unmatched, producing a syntax error.

Arguably Haml should check that the script line does in fact start a block when following lines are indented a create a more informative error, but currently it doesn’t.